# Do not paste rich text formatting works only for the first text area

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you paste formatted text in the following two text areas, you can see that only for the first text area, there is no formatting. It should be for the second one, and maybe for a third one, the same. How is it possible to do that?

```js
var editable = document.querySelector("[contenteditable]")

editable.addEventListener("paste", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var clipboard = e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain")
  document.execCommand("insertText", false, clipboard)
})
```

```css
* {
  font-family: inherit;
}

div {
  font-family: Papyrus;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">One: At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>

<div contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">Two: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>
```

Would be very happy if somebody could help me! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) only returns the first match in the page

You need to use [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and loop over the collection to add a listener to each one

```js
var editable = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable]");

editable.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("paste", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var clipboard = e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");  
    document.execCommand("insertText", false, clipboard);
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: inherit;
}

div {
  font-family: Papyrus;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">One: At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>

<div contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">Two: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! <333